# FormData not appending the data

Tags: javascript

I am just scratching my head, and do not understand, what happens here. This code has worked both in production and in my developer environment.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) is the reference, I do exactly the same.

```
var fileToUpload = $('#productsFile').prop('files')[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileToUpload);
formData.append('action', 'csvUpload');
formData.append('siteId', $('#siteId').val());
console.log($('#siteId').val());
console.log(fileToUpload);
console.log(formData);
```

The output in the console:

```
10
File { name: "H00447.PriceList.csv", lastModified: 1464960003935, lastModifiedDate: Date 2016-06-03T13:20:03.935Z, size: 14859917, type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" }
FormData {  }
```

Object has created, the values are fine, so what could be the problem here? Tested with Firefox Developer Edition.

**EDIT**

Here is the code to send the data to the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl, // point to server-side PHP script 
    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    type: 'post'
}).done(function (msg) {
    if (parseInt(msg) !== 0) {
        alert(msg);
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
}).fail(function (msg) {
    alert('Error: ' + msg.statusText);
});
```

In the `ajax.php` I just `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and shows me an empty array.

**EDIT2**

I tried it on another localhost environment, I've just added some random keys and values, and everything was fine, even in FF and Chrome.

So I came back to this issue, and just commented out the `fileToUpload` section.

The other two value was in the `$_POST`. If I add the file, the `$_POST` will be empty.

Something wrong with the file.

**EDIT3**

No I just tested it with a small file, what is about 3-4Kb, and everything is fine. My production file is 14Mb, I think that will be the problem.

**SOLUTION**

This whole thing because of the filesize. I incrased the post limit, and max file size in `php.ini` and viola. Things are works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't introspect `FormData`, try sending it to the server and check there if data was sent.

Comment: @Rudi `FormData` is build in object.

Comment: @jcubic I dumped `$_REQUEST` in my `ajax.php` an empty array.

Comment: @jcubic Cool, thanks

Comment: Even though you use a different case, I would not use a variable name that already exists as a build in function.

Comment: @Rudi your solution will work but you need to pass the key as argument like `console.log(formData.getAll('action'));`

Comment: @jcubic It works, `Array [ "csvUpload" ]` but how can I pass the whole `FormData` object to the ajax, and why is it empty in this case?

Comment: Show your code that sends the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to log keys and values:

```
formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
  console.log(key, value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is send but you need to use POST not GET:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('action', 'csvUpload');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Nothing in the `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: Intresting, I checked it on another localhost site, and on that it works as I expected. I need to dig deeper what could happen here.